# What does $\Delta$ mean in context of vector calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm reading an article that has a formula for $\Delta \phi(x)$, where $\phi : \mathbf{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ and $x \in \mathbf{R}^2$ and $\Delta \phi(x) : \mathbf{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$

From context I think it has to do with the gradient of $\phi$.  Specifically I strongly suspect it means $|\nabla \phi(x)|$, but I've never seen $\Delta$ used to mean that.  Is that a common practice?

The paper specifically is [Transfinite mean value interpolation](http://folk.uio.no/erikd/pdf/mvinterp.pdf), bottom of page 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Delta$ is the Laplace operator defined as

$$\Delta \phi=\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}=\langle\nabla,\nabla\rangle\phi$$

Comment: Ah, I was so close and yet so far :)  Thanks!